# Which layer for least cost path analysis

Tags: qgis, srtm, cost-path, hillshade

New QGIS user here, so maybe it's kind of a stupid question. I want to calcualte the least cost path between two points but I don't know which layer to use. I have two layers, one is a hillshade layer and the other one a color relief map. I tried both and both worked, but which one si the correct layer to use?

Comment: Hi and welcome to GIS.SE! I think we could help you if you focus your question on the type of cost you want to minimize when traversing the raster. Is this cost defined as distance or steepness, body energy? Looking at the units of your rasters could help too (eg. it is difficult to calculate cost with sun radiation intensity stored in a hillshade).

Answer (score 1):

You need at least a Digital Elevation Model, depending on the algorithm you want to use. Also you may need a "friction surface".The last one varies, some use a slope model and some use more complex Raster layers. I will not use the shaded relief model to calculate the least cost path, may be for display only

Comment: Check this: https://gracilis.carleton.ca/CUOSGwiki/index.php/Evaluating_Landscape_Permeability_in_Quantum bear in mind that is just an example